# beta2 maxRotation set to 0 causes labels to overlap

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using a Chart.js beta 2 line chart. I'd like my x axis labels not to rotate, because it messes up my layout. I'm setting the options to have the ticks.maxRotation property set to 0. When I do so the labels are not skipped properly, but overlap instead.

```
this.options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                maxRotation: 0
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

I also tried providing a ticks.userCallback to only show certain labels and skip myself, however I found doing this not only removes the label from the xAxis display, but also from the tooltip. I always want the tooltips to display the label.

So, what is the best way to keep labels oriented at 0 rotation and not have them overlap ?